# Find partial text in VBA grabs 1 partially incorrect record

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which finds a certain value in each (hope so) cell in a column but it does only grab 1 record and end the code. The table is like this

Q10 To Q20 ("FD\grapes, "FD\squash, "FD\pineapple, "FD\apple)

Then i used this code which only shows pineapple and not apple

```
Dim f As Range
For each f In Range("Q10:Q20").Find(what:="apple", lookat:=xlPart)
If f Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ""
Else
f = "apples"
End If
Next f
```

it only detects pineapple which is not correct, I want to grab the apple but the '"FD\' is not constant. And after I find the apple I want to change it to apple

Comment: specify the match parameter

Comment: @ me how - Can you be more specific Sir. Thanks

Comment: type `Range("A1").Find(` and look at the intelli-sense syntax. It takes a few [optional parameters](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/optional-parameters-and-paramarray-in-vba/) and you have got to find the [right one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx) for an exact match. `lookat:=xlWhole` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **.Find(...)** will only execute once cuz you're asking it to find something in the range, instead of what is intended (find in each cell).  I will recommend using **instr** instead:

```
Dim f As Range
For Each f In Range("Q10:Q20")
If InStr(1, f.Value, "apple") = 0 Then
MsgBox ""
Else
f.Value = "apples"
End If
Next f
```

Comment: @Patrick You may want to look at me now's comment where you will learn how .find works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sir Alex. It worked. I also found a way to differentiate apple from pineapple by placing a '.' in between. Thanks for the help.